# how to handle when use module

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have one module, such as A.pm, in this A.pm, it will read and write one certain conf file, such A.conf.
Now in my perl script file: 1_perl.pl, I use A.pm to reset certain value in A.conf file and also use A.pm to write this value in 2_perl.pl. So my question is how to hand this process in background? It will produce 2 A.pm instance to handle this or just one instance ?

Please give more details about this , thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

Perl modules are just loadable blobs of functions and data -- modules are not processes, so your question doesn't really make sense.

If you want your module to create a background process to write out the configuration file, that's certainly doable, but you'll have to implement it yourself. Deciding how to manage these processes is up to you.